# Edit Django files on Heroku without editing my database files

Tags: django, heroku, git-push

I wanna make some changes to my Django site running on Heroku, how can i upload my new changes with git push without touching my database, so i don't loose any data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would typically have your database on a seperate dyno on heroku. For e.g. you might have configured heroku-postgresql to keep your DB. When you `git push` to heroku it only moves your application to the heroku server, and doesn't overwrite the database, i.e. unless you're using some DB like sqlite3 which might be saving the data in a local file within the application directory.